# How to output a different date format. Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, datetime

I am using Ruby On Rails 4 and twitter-bootstrap-rails, to the client wants to dislay dates in this format:

`14 September 2013` Well pretty cool, there we go:

```
    var start = $("#project_start_date").datepicker({
        format: 'dd MM yyyy',
        autoclose: true
    })
```

However when the date is saved to the database it is saved as "2013-09-14". Well cool, however when I want to edit the page I see the following:

`2013-09-14` as the output of the field :( Not good hey.

So how would you output the date in a given format (I probably need `@start_date.stftime("%d %B %Y")`.

Just wanted to say, that:

1. getter methods didn't do the job: `def start_date() @start_date.stftime("%d %B %Y") end`
2. before_validation also didn't do:

```
 
before_validation :date_validation

  def date_validation
    @start_date = self.start_date.strftime("%D %m %Y")
    @end_date =   self.end_date.strftime("%d %m %Y")
  end
```

PS I am using Postgres.

Comment: Are you saving the date as as a string or date in the database?

Comment: When you say 'didn't do the job', you mean it didn't work as expected or was there an error? If so, what was the error?

Comment: In any case, instead of adding the date formatting code in your model, you should consider using `draper` or any other presentation layer concept. http://railscasts.com/episodes/286-draper

Comment: Saving as a date in Postgres

Answer (score 1):

Check whether the date is being stored as a string in the database as thats what it seems.

Try generating a migration and making sure you have a date column, something like this

```
def change    
   change_column :table_name, :start_date, :datetime
   change_column :table_name, :end_date, :datetime
end
```

That way, you can then use strftime to format it as you mentioned above.

Comment: It's saved as date in PostgreSQL

Answer (score 0):

To change the format in which the date is saved in the database, add this piece of code to the `environment.rb` file.

```
# environment.rb :

ActiveSupport::CoreExtensions::Date::Conversions::DATE_FORMATS.merge!(
     :default => "%d %B %Y"
)
```

Comment: environment.rb:7:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant ActiveSupport::CoreExtensions (NameError)

Answer (score 0):

I decided to make this old Q complete by answering it.

Aside from using draper that was mentioned in a comment, the easiest way is to [override AR getter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28362793/673826), not in a validation, i.e.

```
# in your model
def start_date
  self[:start_date].strftime("%D %m %Y")
end
```