# How can I overwrite a getter method in an ActiveRecord model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord, getter-setter

I'm trying to overwrite a getter method for an ActiveRecord model. I have an attribute called `name` in the model `Category`, and I'd like to be able to do something like this:

```
def name
  name_trans || name
end
```

If `name_trans` attribute is not nil, then return it, else return `name` attribute. How would I do this?

This should then be called normally like this:

```
@category.name
```

Answer (score 167, accepted):

The [Rails Style Guide](https://github.com/bbatsov/rails-style-guide#read-attribute) recommends using `self[:attr]` over `read_attribute(:attr)`.

You can use it like this:

```
def name
  name_trans || self[:name]
end
```

Comment: Why is it better? Don't just link to a other sites, include the relevant bits here. Links can become invalid

Comment: For a bit more context see here: https://github.com/bbatsov/rails-style-guide/issues/155

Answer (score 101):

Update: The preferred method according to the [Rails Style Guide](https://github.com/bbatsov/rails-style-guide#read-attribute) is to use `self[:name]` instead of `read_attribute` and `write_attribute`.  I would encourage you to skip my answer and instead prefer [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28362793/229044).

---

You can do it exactly like that, except that you need to use `read_attribute` to actually fetch the value of the name attribute and avoid the recursive call to the `name` method:

```
def name 
  name_trans || read_attribute(:name)
end
```

Comment: Any idea why Rubocop prefers `self[:name]` over `read_attribute[:name]` ?

Answer (score 28):

I would like to add another option for overwriting getter method, which is simply ：super.

```
def name
  name_trans || super
end
```

this works not just on attributes getter method, but also associations getter methods， too。

Comment: This is what the Rails guides currently recommend, for getters AND setters: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#class-ActiveRecord::Base-label-Overwriting+default+accessors

Answer (score 5):

Overriding the getter and using `read_attribute` does not work for associations, but you can use `alias_method_chain` instead.

```
def name_with_override
  name_trans || name_without_override
end

alias_method_chain :name, :override
```

Comment: Can you give a proper example... ?

Comment: Well. I just saw the [doco](http://apidock.com/rails/Module/alias_method_chain). Now if I call `name` on the model object, which one will be called -`name_with_override` or `name_without_override` ?

Comment: `name` will now call `name_with_override`. If you want to call the original method for some reason, you can call `name_without_override`.

Comment: O I see.. Thanks for your replies//

Comment: This answer is deprecated in rails 5: [Deprecate alias_method_chain in favour of Module#prepend](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/19434)

Answer (score 2):

If you using store attributes like this

```
store :settings, accessors: [:volume_adjustment]
```

or 
using gems like 
`hstore_accessor` [gem link](https://github.com/devmynd/hstore_accessor)

So you ended up using `store` method on model, then to override those method you can't use `self.read_attribute`, you must use instead `super` like that:

```
def partner_percentage
  super.to_i || 10
end
```

Answer (score 2):

If someone want update the value after `name_trans` in getter method, you could use self[:name]=.

```
def name
  self[:name] = name_trans || self[:name]
  # don't do this, it will cause endless loop
  # update(name: name_trans)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Rails read_attribute method. 
[Rails docs](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/read_attribute)

Comment: while this link might answer the question, link only answers are not allowed on SO, please add some context to your answer from what's behind that link. Thanks! :)