# ActiveRecord validates works on DB record or getter method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a question about the ActiveRecord's `validates`

For example, with this code:

```
class Person < ApplicationRecord
  validates :name, presence: true

  def name
    'hello world'
  end
end
```

There is a getter method `name` to return a string as the name. There is also a column in the database table, whose name is `name`.

I understand that, when we call `person.name`, the method (not the db record) is used. However, for the `validates`, do we use the method's return value or the db records to check?

I tried to read the ActiveRecord source code, but quickly got lost :-( Any help or pointer is much appreciated!

Comment: Could just try it…

Comment: There is no such thing as the "getter method" and the "db record". Without the definition of `name` `ActiveModel` uses `method_missing` to determine if the method name is actually an attribute and if so it returns its value. When you define `name` the method is no longer missing and thus you get the return value from that method call. In both cases the validation hooks simply call the method. e.g. `obj.send(:name)` [See Here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v7.0.0/activemodel/lib/active_model/validations.rb#L402)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It uses the getter method. It's straight-forward to test:

```rb
class Person < ApplicationRecord
  validates :name, presence: true

  def name
    binding.irb
  end
end
```

Then in the Rails console:

```rb
irb(main):002:0> Person.create!

From: /Users/foo/app/models/person.rb @ line 5 :

    3: 
    4:   def name
 => 5:     binding.irb
    6:   end
    7:
```

And if you simply `exit` from there (implying `nil`) you'll receive:

```
Validation failed: Name can't be blank (ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid)
```

Comment: Thanks @anothermh! Is there a beautiful way to let the validates to use the db records, instead of getter?

Comment: Use `self[:name]` from within the getter. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/28362793/3784008 for more.

Comment: Yes, that works and actually I am using that in my code :-) My question is actually, how can I not involve the getter function in the `validates` path at all? Is it doable?

Comment: You probably want to make a [custom validator](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#performing-custom-validations) that can make the calls necessary to return what you want.